# I want to convert SQL to Linq query. given below the sql query

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
select * 
from HrNotifications n 
where HrmEmployeeId not in (select HrmemployeeId 
                            from HrNotificationViewEmployees 
                            where HrmEmployeeId = n.HrmemployeeId  
                              and HrNotificationId = n.Id)
```

Comment: Let us see what you have tried

Comment: can you show the table structure

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var NotifyAnnouncementEmp = (from Ntfy in dbContext.NotificationDbSet
                                 where !dbContext.NotificationViewEmployeeDbSet.Where(w => w.HrmEmployeeId == EmpId && w.HrNotificationId==Ntfy.Id).Select(s => s.HrmEmployeeId).ToList().Contains(EmpId) && Ntfy.HrmEmployeeId==EmpId
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Ntfy.Id,
                                     Ntfy.MessageSubject,
                                     Ntfy.Message
                                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Im relatively new to linq. but this is how i would do it

```
 var innerquery=HrNotifications.join(HrNotificationViewEmployees,c=>c.Id,ca=>ca.HrNotificationId,(c,ca)=>new{HrNotifications=c,HrNotificationViewEmployees=ca}).select(s=>s.HrNotificationViewEmployees.HrmemployeeId).ToList();

 var result=HrNotifications.where(s=>!innerquery.Contains(s.HrmEmployeeId));
```